# A follow-up to the regular hexagon question

Tags: probability, geometry

This is a follow-up to the [regular hexagon question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93785/regular-hexagon-on-a-colored-sphere).

The problem statement was:

> Suppose we have a sphere and more than a half of its surface is red. Prove or disprove that we can place all vertices of a regular hexagon on this sphere and at least four vertices of it will be placed on red surface.

As far as I understand the solution suggested by Lopsy:

Let $\Omega := $ the set of all regular hexagon inscribed in the sphere. Together with some appropriate $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ (by the way, would that be simply $2^\Omega$, or not?) and $P$, they make the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

For $k=1,…, 6$, we define $M_k := \{ \omega \in \Omega \ \ | \ \ $the $k^\text{th}$ vertex of $\omega$ is red$\}$, and the following random variables: $X_k := \chi_{M_k}$ and $X:=X_1+…+X_6$. Then:

\begin{align} 
E(X) &= E(X_1+…+X_6)
 \\  &= E(X_1)+…+E(X_6)
 \\  &= P(M_1)+…+P(M_6)
 \\  &>3
\end{align}

And so there exists at least one regular hexagon on this sphere with at least four vertices of it placed on red surface.

**My question is:**

Where did we use the properties of the objects (hexagon, surface)? What is we replace *sphere* with *circle* in the setup? What if we replace *hexagon* with some other figure which touches the sphere in six points? Go $3D$ with an octahedron? Or just with any six points for that matter? What would it change in our proof?

Or to put it differently, I feel uneasy about $\Omega$. Since we could define it in so many ways, how do we know that we aren't counting any irrelevant objects?

That's the first time I see a proof which makes use of the probabilistic method, and I don't feel convinced which makes me think that I'm missing out some very important insights. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: The whole difficulty in the proof is putting a probability measure on $\Omega$ and proving that $P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid \text{the $k$-th vertex of $\omega$ is red}\}) = P(\text{a random point on the sphere is red})$

Comment: @mercio: Oh, I didn't even pay attention to this aspect and just assumed it tacitly. What measure can we put on $\Omega$?

Comment: My guess would be to pick $\Omega$ to be in fact the group of rotations of the sphere, and use its Haar measure $\mu$. Then if $P \in S^2$, you can define for $A$ a measurable subset of $S^2$, $\mu_P(A) = \mu(\{\rho \mid \rho(P) \in A\})$, which gives you a measure $\mu_P$ on $S^2$. Then you essentially have to show that $\mu_P$ doesn't depend on $P$ (easy because the action of $\Omega$ on the sphere is transitive) and that $\mu_P$ is secretly the standard Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $S^2$ (I don't think this is easy !)

Comment: @mercio: Unfortunately, that's beyond my current knowledge. I have seen a few proofs to similar problems (inscribing various things into a painted sphere) yet none of them involved the rigor you're talking about. Do you think that my confusion is rooted in this aspect of the proof? I mean, can't we still replace the hexagon with some other six-point-on-the-sphere figure and go through the same reasoning (including the remarks in your two comments)?